# How to get location from Twitter user profile using Beautiful Soup4?

Tags: json, twitter, beautifulsoup, geolocation, location

So, I am trying to get the location text in the profile of a given Twitter account

```
handles = ['IndieWire' , 'AFP', 'UN']

for x in handles:
    url= "https://twitter.com/" + x
    try:
        html = req.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to fetch page for url {url} due to: {e}")
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
    try:
        label = soup.find('span',{'class':"ProfileHeaderCard-locationText"})
        label_formatted = label.string.lstrip()
        label_formatted = label_formatted.rstrip()
        if label_formatted != "":
            location_list.append(label_formatted)
            print(x + ' : ' + label_formatted)
        else:
            location_list.append(label_formatted)
            print(x + ' : ' + 'Not found')
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            label2 = soup.findAll('span',{"class":"ProfileHeaderCard-locationText"})[0].get_text()
            label2 = str(label2)
            label2_formatted = label2.lstrip()
            label2_formatted = label2_formatted.rstrip()
            location_list.append(label_formatted)
            print(x + ' : ' + label2_formatted)
        except:
            print(x + ' : ' + 'Not found')
    except:
            print(x + ' : ' + 'Not found')
```

This code used to work when I used it a few months ago. I changed it a little bit now after checking the Twitter page source but I still cant get the locations. Hope you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mobile version of Twitter to get location.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


handles = ['IndieWire' , 'AFP', 'UN']

ref = 'https://twitter.com/{h}'
headers = {'Referer': '',}
url = 'https://mobile.twitter.com/i/nojs_router?path=/{h}'

for h in handles:
    headers['Referer'] = ref.format(h=h)
    soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.post(url.format(h=h), headers=headers).content, 'html.parser' )
    loc = soup.select_one('.location')
    if loc:
        print(h, loc.text)
    else:
        print(h, 'Not Found')
```

Prints:

```
IndieWire New York, NY
AFP France
UN New York, NY
```